# Create wheel without building dependencies

Tags: python, setup.py, python-wheel

I have a sample project:

```
test/
    - __init__.py
    - module.py
    - setup.py
```

`setup.py` is just

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='test', install_requires=['numpy'])
```

Then when I call `pip wheel .`, it automatically makes a wheel for `numpy`. Can I make it not do that? It's my understanding that when you install a wheel, it will automatically go download and install any missing dependencies. Is the `numpy` wheel needed for making my test wheel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's just the way that pip rolls, but if you wheely want to omit the numpy build then you can turn around and give this command a spin:

```
pip wheel --no-deps .
```

*Note:* if the correct numpy wheel was already existing, it would be skipped anyway.  No need to reinvent the thing...